# SQLAlchemy find all duplicates in children

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been looking for solutions to this but I couldn't find anything on finding duplicates with SQLAlchemy.

I have a parent-child type relationship, and I'm looking to find all the duplicates in the children on a specific column.

I tried iterating over each parent and counting on the column, but it gave me results that didn't make sense.

```
parents = session.query(parent).all()
for parent in parents:
    dups = session.query(child).filter_by(parentid=parent.id).group_by(child.foo_column).count()
    if dups > 0:
        # do action on duplicates
```

How can I get the duplicate children, or is there even a single query that could return all the duplicates?

EDIT:
Table definitions:

```
class parent(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parentid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    foo_column = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'))

    parent = relationship('parent',
                            backref=backref('children'))

    foo = relationship('foo')
```

The `foo_column` I'm interested in contains just integer id's, so a duplicate would just be where `foo1.id == foo2.id`.

Comment: Can you provide your table definitions and what constitutes a duplicate for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve requires a self join. Think of how you would do it in SQL. Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT child_1.id as dup1, child_2.id as dup2
FROM child as child_1 JOIN child as child_2 
     ON child_1.parentid = child_2.parentid
WHERE child_1.foo_column = child_2.foo_column;
```

Translating that to SQL Alchemy is straightforward:

```
child_2 = aliased(child)
dups = session.query(child).
               join(child_2, child.parentid == child_2.parentid).
               filter(child.foo_column == child_2.foo_column).
               with_entities(child.id.label('dup1'), child_2.id.label('dup2'))
```

Comment: The with_entities part was giving me an error, but otherwise it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I see what was wrong there - `with_entities` expects a `*entities` arg. Fixed it.